# LISP: read number from user and commpare with array index

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp

Hello guys I'm new In functional programming Really it is not Clear for me anyone can help me ?
My Question just for getting the philosophy of writing on Functional programming language for example how I can write a program in Lisp language for reading the user inputs and compare the user inputs and index of array ?
other part on my question how we can specify the index of array in lisp ?
for example I was did this program in a numerical programming language like C# but how I can do it in LISP ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the number:");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] numbers = {"0","1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
            string[] words = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            {
                if (name == numbers[i].ToString())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(words[i].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Common Lisp isn't a functional language … but then, C# isn't a numerical one, either … More importantly, what have you tried in CL so far? What problem are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common Lisp is multi-paradigm, not purely functional. There's really no reason to change your code algorithm from C#. If you want to write in a procedural style, you can continue to do so.

```
(defun main (&rest args)
  (declare (ignore args))   
  (loop
     (princ "Enter the number:")
     (finish-output)
     (let ((name (read-line))
           (numbers #("0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"))
           (words #("one" "two" "three" "four" "five")))
       (loop for i from 0 upto (length numbers)
          when (equal name (elt numbers i))
          do (print (elt words i))))))
```

Unfortunately, your example doesn't work correctly in C#, so it's really hard to guess what you would want it to do in Lisp. The following is a general-purpose version that will do the same thing for any number (not just 0-4), but still follows the “shape” of your C# example.

```
(defun main ()
  (loop
     (fresh-line)
     (princ "Enter a number:")
     (finish-output)
     (let* ((*read-eval* nil)
            (number (read)))
       (format t "~&~r" (1+ number)))))
```

Comment: If you know that it is a number you want to read, you can use `parse-integer` (in the standard) or `parse-number` (a library).  That is much better than using `read` which you would have to secure against malicious input.

Comment: @BRP from the first part it doesn't work perfectly because it print all index fo Array I want just print the index are equal the user inputs and for the second part  what is mean by '(format t "~&~r" (1+ number)' why it not work when I try to just print the number without add one !

Comment: @Svante Yes, but this follows the shape of the C# code, and accepts rationals et al.  I would probably use read-line, but

Comment: @Ega these should both produce the same output as your original program, only the second one handles all numbers and not just 0-4.

Comment: You can look up formatting codes by spelling out the tilde: "CLHS FORMAT TILDE R" for example

Comment: @BRPocock: the C# version doesn't exit when someone enters `#.(exit)`.  If you want numbers, use `parse-number`.  If you do use `read`, at least bind `*read-eval*` to `nil`.

Comment: Unfortunately, CL doesn't define a #'parse-number, but yeah, I'll stick in *read-eval* nil. I don't intend anyone to take this as an example of a good or useful program at all; just demonstrates that the structure of a CL program can be effectively the same as a C# (or insert-language-here) program.

Comment: and, yes, everyone has their own parse-decimal / parse-float / parse-number routine in the toolkit, but sticking with the ANSI set for this one :-)